# You are not allowed to access this feed. - GET https://sencha.myget.org/F/community/npm/@sencha%2fext-gen

Tags: npm, extjs, sencha

Estoy intentando instalar

```
npm install -g @sencha/ext-gen
```

Ya inicié sesión en:

```
npm login --registry=https://sencha.myget.org/F/community/npm/ --scope=@sencha

Password: Logged in to scope @sencha on https://sencha.myget.org/F/community/npm/.
```

ya estoy registrado en https://sencha.myget.org/

Segui los pasos que indica: https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/7.0.0-CE/guides/getting_started/mobile_desktop_application/getting_started_with_npm.html

Para poner el usuario de acuerdo al correo y la clave no funciona.

Utilice el usuario y clave que me llego al correo, cambie la clave y no me permite instalar, me indica lo siguiente:

> You are not allowed to access this feed. - GET https://sencha.myget.org/F/community/npm/@sencha%2fext-gen
> In most cases, you or one of your dependencies are requesting
> a package version that is forbidden by your security policy, or
> on a server you do not have access to.
> complete log of this run can be found in: C:\Users\Usuario\AppData\Local\npm-cache_logs\2023-08-18T01_57_04_963Z-debug-0.log

Si me permite acceder a la version GPL

> npm login --registry=https://sencha.myget.org/F/gpl/npm/ --scope=@sencha

> npm install -g @sencha/ext-gen

Pero me esta dando errores al intentar compilar:

> ext-gen app -a -t moderndesktop -n ModernApp

> npm start

Asi que quiero seguir intentando con la version Community.

Espero alguien me pueda ayudar.

Saludos